# iphone dev - launch Waze with hebrew address search query

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

this is my current code:

```
NSSString *waze = @"waze://";

BOOL canOpen = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:waze]];
if(canOpen){
NSString *url = @"waze://?q=הר לעמק";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
}
```

if the query is in english then it works fine.
tried to encode using `stringWitjUTF8String`. didnt help.

solution ?

Comment: Did you contact waze support?

Comment: not yet. maybe someone here has the answer. and i dont see they have developer supprt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried escaping?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```